# Typeguard for property

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say we have a class like the following:

```
class RawResult {
  private raw: string | undefined;
  get exists(): boolean {
    return this.raw !== undefined;
  }
  decode(): Result | undefined {
    if (this.raw === undefined) {
       return undefined;
    }
    return someExpensiveDecoding(this.raw); 
  }
}
```

Is there a way of telling the TS compiler that `result.exists` implies that `result.decode()` will not be `undefined`.

This is based on [Firestore `DocumentSnapshot`'s API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot), in which you have the `exists` property and the `data` method. However, in order to ensure `data()` is not `undefined` we need to do something like:

```
const data = result.data()
if (data) {
   // do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with property, but if you can convert that getter to a normal method, it can be done like:

```
type Result = {}

interface RawResultExists extends RawResult {
    decode(): Result
}

class RawResult {
    private raw: string | undefined;
    exists(): this is RawResultExists {
        return this.raw !== undefined;
    }
    decode() {
        if (this.raw === undefined) {
            return undefined;
        }
        return this.raw as Result
    }
}

const rawResult = new RawResult();

if (rawResult.exists()) {
    const data = rawResult.decode()
}
```

Comment: Here is an issue talking about why properties don't support typeguards https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7150

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can tell the compiler you know what you're doing using the [`!` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
if (rawResult.exists()) {
    const result = rawResult.decode()!   // always a Result
}
```